# Find out address an index in a 2D array given matrix elements are sorted in 1D Array

Tags: arrays, matrix, data-structures

**A lower triangular matrix of dimension 50*50 is stored optimally on one dimensional array. The base address of the array is 4321.
What is the address of the element (34,23) of the matrix if the array indexing starts with 0 and the matrix indexing starts with (1, 1) ?**

Can someone provide me the answer for this one. stuck can't solve because i think i need to apply the column or row major order method here but i am not getting the answer. Any other way to solve this one.

Answer (score 0):

Say Matrix is M, so the distance of element M(34,23) from the beginning is [1+2+3+.. 33]+[23 elements] = 584.

The base address of the array is 4321. Hence the address of M(34,23)element in the array should be 4321+584-1(for array starting at 0) = 4904.

Comment: Thanks Vikas, So we have to add 23 elements not 22. because we want 23rd column element address right. It should have been till 22 right?

Comment: Good question. As the array index starts at 0 so the first element is 0 then the 23rd element will be at 22. Hence it should be +22. Making changes in my response.

Comment: Yeah now i got it. Thank you so much vikas again. cheers!

Comment: Great!! Happy to help.